# Elasticsearch не хочет выполнять перколацию в несколько потоков

Tags: многопоточность, elasticsearch, multiprocessing

Использую механизм перколации в Elasticsearch 2.3.3. 
Если делать запрос в перколатор в один поток, то он занимает примерно 0.5 секунды и это нормально:

```
{u'total': 0, u'took': 452, u'_shards': {u'successful': 12, u'failed': 0, u'total': 12}} TIME 0.467885982513
```

Если же сделать в 4 потока, то на удивление, время возрастает в 4 раза:

```
{u'total': 0, u'took': 1837, u'_shards': {u'successful': 12, u'failed': 0, u'total': 12}} TIME 1.890885982513
```

Запросы делаются с помощью модуля Python celery. 
Дальше еще интереснее, поставил в 20 потоков и эластик совсем завис, в логах такая ошибка:

> RemoteTransportException[[test_node01][192.168.69.142:9300][indices:data/read/percolate[s]]];
>   nested: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution of
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4@7906d a8a on
>   EsThreadPoolExecutor[percolate, queue capacity = 1000,
>   org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@31a1c278[Running,
>   pool size = 16, active threads = 16, queued tasks = 1000, compl eted
>   tasks = 156823]]]; Caused by: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected
>   execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4@7906da8a
>   on EsThreadPoolExecutor[percolate, queue capacity = 1000,
>   org.elasticsearch.common.util
>   .concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@31a1c278[Running, pool size = 16,
>   active threads = 16, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 156823]]]

Эластик запущен на машине, где 16 ядер и 32 гб оперативной памяти.
В чем может быть проблема?